# RubyMine 7.0.2 Stops Frequently With Very Long Pauses

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine, rubymine-7

I have been using RubyMine now for a couple of years, and loving it, but recently it's become almost unusable due to the IDE frequently pausing for long periods (anywhere between 5 seconds and a minute.)

I'll simply start typing and there will be a pause, then the text will appear and a few seconds later there will be another pause. Then perhaps 30 seconds later when I try and do something else. It's getting extremely frustrating.

This appears to be due to the project having grown quite large.

I have been trying to find out how to fix this and have found info on adjusting the Java options such as max memory size and the like. I have experimented with these numbers, but so far it hasn't had any effect. The current settings in RubyMine64.vmoptions are:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx3192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Note: If -Xmx is 2048m or less, RubyMine runs out of memory on its indexing operations.

Also, I'm using a HP Laptop with an i7 CPU (8 cores) and 8GB of RAM running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Up until now it's been blazing fast.

I suspect it's either something to do with Java garbage collection, or perhaps RubyMine itself trying to manage\index the source. However, when these pauses occur the system monitor utility doesn't always show the CPU usage significantly increase.

Sometimes CPU hits 100%, but just as often it's sitting at 3% to 10% on all cores when these pauses hit.

Can anyone shed any light on this, or why it's happening?

I'm also wondering if there's a way to turn off some of the RubyMine features that could be causing this, like indexing.

Comment: Is it while you're trying to complete I18n keys, by any chance? Had problem with these. Rubymine would just freeze on every keystroke for 10-20 seconds. They fixed it in latest versions. Outside of I18n key context, it was fine, though.

Comment: No, it can happen when I'm doing anything. For example, it just happened when I added a new controller method.

Comment: If I were you, I'd try the latest version. Performance fixes arrive all the time. There might be one for your case.